# Set emergency bypass on macOS?

Tags: messages, contacts, do-not-disturb, ios

iOS has a great Emergency Bypass feature for allowing certain contacts to ring through to you even when in Do Not Disturb mode.  But on macOS, DND prevents any alerts on incoming text messages, even from those set as EB in iOS.  This has caused me to miss urgent texts from my other half many, many times when my mac is in DND mode and my phone is not within earshot.

Is there any way to set specific contacts as EB on macOS?

To be clear, this is not an iOS question.  This is specifically and only a question about setting EB for contacts on macOS.  I'm running High Sierra on my MBP but if a newer version of macOS had this feature, I'd consider upgrading for it.

Comment: Is emergency bypass another way to say you add them to your favorites or are you in a different screen? It's not clear what you refer to. Apple has emergency contacts, but that's for SOS situations - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208076

Comment: No, Emergency Bypass is a feature of iOS.  It allows you to specify certain contacts who will always ring (and vibrate, and alert) through at all times no matter what.  But it doesn't seem to exist on macOS and I'm looking to see if I'm wrong about that.  Nothing to do with favorites at all.

Comment: This is a feature of Do Not Disturb - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204321 - I'm sure lots of people call it that, but the only thing you can do in contacts is add someone as an emergency contact - is that what you're tapping. Again - if you show a screen shot people may be able to help if you're not using the feature name Apple has in documents

Comment: No, this is not a feature of DND.  It is on your individual contacts' edit page.  Not in DND settings anywhere.  It is called Emergency Bypass.  https://www.imore.com/how-receive-messages-specific-contacts-do-not-disturb-mode

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an iOS feature only.  What you can do is provide [Apple Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) and make a feature request

Comment: Thank you @allan for actually addressing the question as asked.  Shame it's not on macOS but, confirms my suspicion.  Now to whoever downvoted... no idea what you were thinking.

Comment: I had the same question (though I never posted it) about 6 or 7 months back so I knew exactly to what you were referring.  Just gave you a +1 because it's actually a good question and a needed feature (I did give feedback back then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the correct answer is... there is no such option in macOS.  Bummer!